# Getting Runtime error on codechef problem "Survive in chocoland"

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying this codechef problem but getting runtime error. Can someone please explain why am I getting this please

This is the link to problem :

https://www.codechef.com/problems/SURVIVE

```
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    a=input().split(" ")
    n=int(a[0])
    k=int(a[1])
    s=int(a[2])
    d=n//k
    sun=7
    i=d
    for i in range(d,s+1,d):
        if i>sun:
            sun+=7

        if (i+1)%7==0:
            break

    if i==s:
        print(s-d)

    elif (i+1)==sun:
        if i==s:
            print(s-d)
        elif i+1==s:
            print(-1)
        else:
            print(-1)

    elif (i+1)<sun:
        if s<sun:
            print(s-d)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: getting runtime error when submitting the code...i think some boundary condition is failing but don't know which

Comment: Yes, you've stated that you're getting a runtime error in the question. You should provide that error message, the offensive line number, a stack trace, etc.

Comment: Its showing NZEC(Non zero exit code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and it appears that the problem is located at the online editor of codechef.
A little workaround and solution for your problem would be to **catch the error with try and except.**

```
try:
    t=int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        a=input().split(" ")
        n=int(a[0])
        k=int(a[1])
        s=int(a[2])
        d=n//k
        sun=7
        i=d
        for i in range(d,s+1,d):
            if i>sun:
                sun+=7

            if (i+1)%7==0:
                break

        if i==s:
            print(s-d)

        elif (i+1)==sun:
            if i==s:
                print(s-d)
            elif i+1==s:
                print(-1)
            else:
                print(-1)

        elif (i+1)<sun:
            if s<sun:
                print(s-d)
except:
    pass
```

Comment: But I am getting runtime error when submitting the code...i think some boundary condition is failing but don't know which

Comment: try using raw_input().split(" ") instead of  int(input()). 
src https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nzec-error-python/

Comment: I just tried your code in an online editor and it runs perfectly fine.
Can you try there to confirm? 
https://repl.it/repls/TwinIckyBruteforceprogramming

Comment: Yes i tried. It's running fine but when i am submitting it to code-chef it's giving the same NZEC error. I think there's some boundary condition which is failing don't know which. And really thank you for your time.